# Ruby Set with custom class to equal basic strings

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to find a custom class in my set given just a string.  Like so:

```
require 'set'

Rank = Struct.new(:name, keyword_init: true) {
  def hash
    name.hash
  end
  def eql?(other)
    hash == other.hash
  end
  def ==(other)
    hash == other.hash
  end
}
one = Rank.new(name: "one")
two = Rank.new(name: "two")
set = Set[one, two]
```

but while `one == "one"` and `one.eql?("one")` are both true, `set.include?("one")` is still false.  what am i missing?

thanks!

Comment: try set.include?(one). You can't look up items in a set by one of the items properties unless you want to scan the whole set. In your case the item in your set is a ruby object (an instance of Rank) and if you want to use include? you must pass the object that might be in the set, not a property of that object.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but worth noting that the source code comments for `Set#include?` (for me, it's at `.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/set.rb`) mention "Note that include? and member? do not test member
equality using == as do other Enumerables."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set` is built upon `Hash`, and `Hash` considers two objects the same if:

> [...] their `hash` value is identical and the two objects are `eql?` to each other.

What you are missing is that `eql?` isn't necessarily commutative. Making `Rank#eql?` recognize strings doesn't change the way `String#eql?` works:

```
one.eql?('one') #=> true
'one'.eql?(one) #=> false
```

Therefore it depends on which object is the hash key and which is the argument to `include?`:

```
Set['one'].include?(one) #=> true
Set[one].include?('one') #=> false
```

In order to make two objects `a` and `b` interchangeable hash keys, 3 conditions have to be met:

1. `a.hash == b.hash`
2. `a.eql?(b) == true`
3. `b.eql?(a) == true`

But don't try to modify `String#eql?` – fiddling with Ruby's core classes isn't recommended and monkey-patching probably won't work anyway because Ruby usually calls the C methods directly for performance reasons.

In fact, making both `hash` and `eql?` mimic `name` doesn't seem like a good idea in the first place. It makes the object's identity ambiguous which can lead to very strange behavior and hard to find bugs:

```
h = { one => 1, 'one' => 1 }
#=> {#<struct Rank name="one">=>1, "one"=>1}

# vs

h = { 'one' => 1, one => 1 }
#=> {"one"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what am i missing?

What you are missing is that `"one"` isn't in your set. `one` is in your set, but `"one"` isn't.

Therefore, the answer Ruby is giving you is perfectly correct.

All that you have done with your implementation of `Rank` is that *any two ranks with the same name are considered to be the same* by a `Hash`, `Set`, or `Array#uniq`. But, a `Rank` is not the same as a `String`.

If you want to be able to have a set-like data structure where you can look up things by one of their attributes, you will have to write it yourself.

Something like (untested):

```rb
class RankSet < Set
  def [](*args)
    super(*args.map(&:name))
  end

  def each
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?

    super {|e| yield e.name }
  end
end
```

might get you started.

Or, instead of writing your own set, you can just use the fact that *any arbitrary rank with the right name* can be used for lookup:

```rb
set.include?(Rank.new(name: "one"))
#=> true
# even though it is a *different* `Rank` object
```